# Why am I getting a "Connection refused" in python? Can't resolve using existing solutions

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, ssl

```
import ssl
import socket

port = 3001

while True:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    ssl_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(s, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, ca_certs='scert.pem')
    ssl_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 3001))
    ssl_socket.write(str(input("Enter two numbers to add:")).encode())
    z = ssl_socket.recv(1024)
    print(z.decode())
    ssl_socket.close()
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

ssl_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 3001))

self._real_connect(addr, False)

socket.connect(self, addr)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I am confused as to what to do. Already tried the methods on the other thread on socket.

Comment: What process is listening to port 3001 on your host?  Do you have any firewall configured on your host?

Comment: Why did you assign the `port` variable and then hard-code `3001` in the `connect()` call?

Comment: Even if I don't hard code, it doesn't work. I don't know much about firewalls, I'm running it on Linux Mint.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to establish a connection between a client and a server. The question has the client code. The server side code works fine @Barmar

Comment: @AndrewHenle gethostbyname

Comment: There is only one 'existing' solution, and it *always* works. Make sure there is something listing at the Ip:port you are trying to connect to. You cannot possibly know that the 'server code works fine' if you can't even connect to it.